# How to create a new array for each unique key in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have an array of objects like so:

```
originalArray = [
    { "16": { "id": 23, "data": "11",}, "17": { "id": 28, "data": "25",},..., "header": "Row 2","id": 6},
    { "16": { "id": 23, "data": "AA",}, "17": { "id": 28, "data": "!!",},..., "header": "Row 2","id": 6},
    .... 
]
```

Where each array item is an object and within each object are several key-value pairs. The key-value pairs (other than the last two items with keys header and id) come in the format

```
"number": {"id": x, "data" = "something"}
```

There can be multiple objects and multiple key-value pairs within the array and the keys are consistent between each object i.e., if there is a key in the first object, it exists in all objects within the array e.g., "16" and "17"

I wrote a method to get the data from that array like so:

```
    createArrays() {
        this.originalArray.forEach(row => {
            Object.entries(row).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                console.log(key, value['data'])
            })
        });
    }
```

This enables me to get the key and the associated data value in each object. For each key (other than the header and id), how can I create a new array and populate it with the value of that key?

Desired outcome based on originalArray:

```
gridData_16 = ["11", "25", ...]
gridData_17 = ["AA", "!!", ...]
....
```

Explanation: we get new arrays that start with gridData_ and the last part comes from the key in the originalArray. Each value in the array comes from the data value for each key with the same number. For example, in originalArray, we have key "16" and "data" that are equal to "11" and "25" for each object in the array so we populate gridData_16 = ["11", "25", ...]

I know I can create an array outside of Object.keys and just populate that single array with all of the data using a .push method. However, that isn't quite the right structure and I'm unsure of how to move forward:

```
    createArrays() {

        this.gridData = []

        this.originalArray.forEach(row => {
            Object.entries(row).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                this.gridData.push(value['data'])
            })
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an object with desired properties and add the values there, then you can simply change it to array if you need it in that format

```js
const originalArray = [
    { "16": { "id": 23, "data": "11",}, "17": { "id": 28, "data": "25",}, "header": "Row 2","id": 6},
    { "16": { "id": 23, "data": "AA",}, "17": { "id": 28, "data": "!!",}, "header": "Row 2","id": 6}
]

function createArrays(originalArray) {

    const gridData = {}
    originalArray.forEach(row => {
        Object.entries(row).forEach(([key, value]) => {
            if(value.data){
              gridData['gridData_' + key] =  gridData['gridData_' + key] || []
              gridData['gridData_' + key].push(value.data)
            }
        })
    });
    return gridData
}

console.log(createArrays(originalArray))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that uses [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to create a result object that groups the data values by key:

```js
const array = [
    {"16": {"id": 23, "data": "11"}, "17": {"id": 28, "data": "25"}, "header": "Row 2", "id": 6},
    {"16": {"id": 23, "data": "AA"}, "17": {"id": 28, "data": "!!"}, "header": "Row 2", "id": 6}
];

const result = array.reduce((a, v) => {
  Object.entries(v).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    if (k.match(/[0-9]+/)) {
      a[k] = a[k] || [];
      a[k].push(v.data);
    }
  });
  
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this without much modifications in your existing code.

Live Demo **:**

```js
// Input Array
let originalArray = [{
  "16": {
    "id": 23,
    "data": "11"
  },
  "17": {
    "id": 28,
    "data": "25"
  },
  "header": "Row 2",
  "id": 6
}, {
  "16": {
    "id": 23,
    "data": "AA"
  },
  "17": {
    "id": 28,
    "data": "!!"
  },
  "header": "Row 2",
  "id": 6
}];

// Declaring an empty object to assignt the result.
let obj = {};

// Iterating original array to access the object enteries and get the values.
originalArray.forEach(row => {
  Object.entries(row).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (!isNaN(key)) {
      if (!obj[key]) {
        obj[key] = [];
      }
      obj[key].push(value.data)
    }
  })
});

// Output
console.log(obj);
```